How to derive the coefficients of the sympy equation
There is such a code:
from sympy import Point3D, Plane

p1 = Plane(Point3D(0, 0, 1),
           Point3D(0, 1, 0),
           Point3D(1, 0, 0))
p2 = p1.equation()
print(p2)

The program outputs the result:
-10*x - 10*y - z + 10
Here a = -10, b=-10, c = -1 and d = 10.
Is there any method to output the coefficients individually?
Since I did not find such a method, I wrote a parser that does this, but since the program does not produce the result in the same format, the parser requires a lot of refinement or even reworking.

I'm not aware of a function that directly gives the coefficients in the desired form.  Internally, the plane is represented by a point and a normal vector. p1.args returns them as a tuple. Your a, b, c form the normal. The negative of the dot product between the normal and a point on the plane gives d. Of course, the same equation can be multiplied by an arbitrary non-zero value.
from sympy import Point3D, Plane

p1 = Plane(Point3D(0, 0, 1),
           Point3D(0, 1, 0),
           Point3D(1, 0, 0))

point, normal = p1.args
p2 = p1.equation()
print(f'{p2 = }')
a, b, c = normal
d = - Point3D(normal).dot(point)
print(f'{a = }, {b = }, {c = }, {d = }')

Output
p2 = -x - y - z + 1
a = -1, b = -1, c = -1, d = 1

Alternatively, you can work with explicit names for the symbols in the equation. And then get a as the coefficient of x.  d will be the value when x, y and z are zero:
from sympy import Point3D, Plane
from sympy.abc import x, y, z

p1 = Plane(Point3D(0, 0, 1),
           Point3D(0, 1, 0),
           Point3D(1, 0, 0))

p2 = p1.equation(x=x, y=y, z=z)
print(f'{p2 = }')
print(f'a = {p2.coeff(x)}, b = {p2.coeff(y)}, c = {p2.coeff(z)}, d = {p2.subs({x: 0, y: 0, z: 0})}')

Output:
p2 = -x - y - z + 1
a = -1, b = -1, c = -1, d = 1


You can use linear_eq_to_matrix:
from sympy import *

p1 = Plane(Point3D(0, 0, 1),
           Point3D(0, 1, 0),
           Point3D(1, 0, 0))
p2 = p1.equation()
print(p2)
# -x - y - z + 1

x, y, z = symbols("x:z", real=True)
A, B = linear_eq_to_matrix(p2, [x, y, z])
print(A)
# -x - y - z + 1
print(B)
# Matrix([[-1]])

a, b, c = A
d = B[0]


Plane already knows how to give the coefficients via normal_vector. And if you pass the Plane.equation() to Poly and evaluate at 0, then you can get the constant:
>>> from sympy import Poly
>>> p1.normal_vector + (Poly(p1.equation())(0,0,0),)
(-1, -1, -1, 1)

The method Expr.as_coefficients_dict() will also give the coefficients mapped to their symbols in a deafultdict (which will return 0 for a key that is not present):
>>> p1.equation().as_coefficients_dict()
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {1: 1, x: -1, y: -1, z: -1})
>>> v=x,y,z
>>> d=p1.equation(*v).as_coefficients_dict();[d[i] for i in v+(1,)]
[-1, -1, -1, 1]

